# Duplicate Files in a directory

Tags: duplicate-files

I Have duplicate file i need count of that files.

Example: **example.html example(1).html**

Output: i want the number of counts for example(1).htnl

Comment: *i want the number of counts for example(1).htnl* - the number is `1` - take it

Comment: Duplicates as in files whose contents are identical, or just ones with similar names (like those `(N)` tags)?

Answer (score 2):

Using `fdupes`:

```
fdupes -1 . | awk '{ print $1, NF }'
```

For an example directory:

```
$ fdupes -1 .  | awk '{ print $1, NF }'
./f 2
./file 2
```

In this example, there are two files with the same contents as `f` (`f` itself is included in that count), and likewise for `file`.

The `-1` option for `fdupes` causes the output to be one line per group of identical files, and the `awk` code will print the first filename along with the count of identical files. The dot denotes "the current directory".